# How to move object with mouse with similar code like this touch script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code for android touch input and want exact code and functionality with mouse pointer movement with persepective camera

```
public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Touch touch;
    private float speedModifier;

    private void Start()
    {
        speedModifier = 0.01f;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                transform.position = new Vector3(
                    transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier,
                    transform.position.y + touch.deltaPosition.y * speedModifier,
                    transform.position.z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
private Vector2 lastMousePosition;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
}

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    var deltaMousePosition = Input.mousePosition - lastMousePosition;
    transform.position += deltaMousePosition * modifier;
    lastMousePosition = Input.MousePosition;
}
```

Note though: This is fully depending on your display resolution as you directly apply the pixel space delta.

You might want to rather use a slightly different approach and use a mathematical plane and raycast to rather directly move in world space.

Something like e.g. this should do it

```
private Vector3 dragOffset;
private Plane dragPlane;

private Camera camera;

private void Awake ()
{
    camera = Camera.main;
}

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit) && hit.transform == transform)
    {
        dragOffset = hit.point - transform.position;
        dragPlane = new Plane(-camera.forward, hit.point);
    }
}

private void OnMouseDrag()
{
    var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if(dragPlane.Raycast(ray, out var distance))
    {
        transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance) + dragOffset;
    }
}
```